# how to flush with shell command

Tags: c, linux, bash, shell

are there an equivalent of the C function `fflush()` for shell command?

```
echo "kkkk"
flush <<< are there some command to execute to flush stdout?
```

Comment: What problem are you experiencing exactly? Try `sync`.

Answer (score -1):

Short answer: There is no need to perform explicit flush for shell scripts. All shell output (via echo) is NOT buffered. The output is immediately sent to the output device. The situation is more complex if the output is piped into another program, which may buffer it's output.

Long answer: consider

```
(echo aaa ; sleep 3  ; echo bbb)
```

Which will display 'aaa', and after 3 seconds delay, 'bbb' - since the pipe construct will result in the the C program using buffered output.

As noted above, if the output is send (via pipe) to a program which will buffer the output, the first line may be delayed, and displayed at the same time as the second line (after the 3 seconds delay). The solution is to force "line buffering" (or no buffering) on other programs in the pipeline.

For example given a simple "C" program to copy stdin to stdout:

```
int main() { char b[256] ; while (fgets(b, sizeof(b), stdin) ) fputs(b, stdout) };
```

and running

```
(echo aaa ; sleep 3 ; echo bbb  ) | a.out | cat
```

Will result in buffering in a.out, showing 'aaa' and 'bbb' after 3 seconds delay.

Answer (score -3):

No, you should never need it.

When a program, such as `echo`, exits, all output data is automatically flushed. If the program has not exited yet then flushing is an internal matter and nothing to do with the shell.

Comment: Well, echo is a bash builtin

Comment: @PavelAnossov: only for efficiency. If bash didn't do that then /bin/echo would do the same job.

Comment: @ams: But what if the intention is to update the progres counter sitting on the same line like `printf "\rCounter %02d" "$cnt"`. Here you do not want to do a newline (only the carriage return). Now it needs to be flushed. How to do that?

Comment: @pepr you still don't need fflush. Incidentally, you need `echo -n` to   not print a line-feed.

Comment: Output can be buffered if piped through `tee`, for example. So it's not always _automatically_ flushed.

Comment: @BenoitDuffez In the case of `tee`, it will flush through that very quickly also, but yes, it's automatic unless you deliberately break it.

Comment: @ams: Not true, piping creates a 4K buffer, so output will be sent to `tee` *only* when it reaches 4K. This will delay printing, and create the need to flush the buffer sooner. `stdbuf` can do that (GNU coreutils).

Comment: @BenoitDuffez No, when `echo` exits the buffer will be flushed. Then `tee` will also exit, and its buffer will be flushed. And anyway, `tee` runs in a line-buffered mode when run from a terminal.

Comment: If you pipe a block of commands in a script, output will be buffered with a 4K buffer. Output will be delayed.

Comment: Yes, non interactive stuff is not line-buffered. I don't believe any of this is relevant to the two-year-old question.

Comment: I stumbled upon it, its age is irrelevant. I saw incorrect or incomplete information and tried to point it out.

Comment: You decided to tell somebody that their sports car isn't going to work off-road. Not helpful.

Comment: @BenoitDuffez You comment is very relevant and it helped me debug a difficult bug. Thanks!